# Does PSEXEC support inter domain execution ?

Tags: psexec

A file has to be copied from current machine to another machine.
once done, he copied file has to be triggered.The problem here is that the machines are located in different network domains.

Does PSEXEC support inter domain execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am doing this. That being said, I am running into issues doing some more complex actions with PsExec never returning once complete. This has worked fine for me though passing -u \[domain][username] and -p [password] and running basic DOS commands. Please see below link for link to my issues.

[PsExec 1.98 (spawned from C# process) never completes when running 7Zip across domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940288/psexec-1-98-spawned-from-c-sharp-process-never-completes-when-running-7zip-acr)